# Displaying variables with special characters "$" or "-" in the name

Tags: php, mysql, xml, ascii, utf

```
stdClass Object
(
    [campaign-ID] => 1
    [campaign_name] => Sample Campaign
    [start_duration] => 2012-04-17
    [end_duration] => 2012-04-17
    [activity$] => 
    [survey_settings] => Ordering K-Cup Packs
    [$limit] => sample
    [$goal] => 
)
```

How to remove the - and $ ? using php?
Because `-` and  `$` sign is valid in mysql, but when I'll try to display it using foreach, it wont work. So what should i do to remove that without editing the field names in the database table?

Comment: when I'll try to display it using foreach, it wont work - should work. details, please..

Comment: it would be wrong to do example:

echo $campaign->$limit;

right?

Comment: Sorry bit how did you get this class ?? `$` is not a valid PHP variable naming

Comment: in mysql you can name a field with a dollar ($) sign. thats what i mean @Baba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am not sure where you got this class but there are so many invalid Naming here

Example

`$goal` `campaign-ID` etc.

I had to reconstruct your class and it looked like this

```
$st= new stdClass();
$st->{"campaign-ID"} = 1 ;
$st->campaign_name = "Sample Campaign" ;
$st->start_duration = "2012-04-17" ;
$st->start_duration = "2012-04-17" ;
$st->{'activity$'} = null ;
$st->survey_settings = "Ordering K-Cup Packs" ;
$st->{'$limit'}  = "sample" ;
$st->{'$goal'} = null ;


$std = new stdClass();
foreach($st as $key => $value)
{
    $key = str_replace(array('$',"-"),array('',"_"),$key);
    $std->{$key} = $value ;
}

echo "<pre>" ;
print_r($std);
```

Output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [campaign_ID] => 1
    [campaign_name] => Sample Campaign
    [start_duration] => 2012-04-17
    [activity] => 
    [survey_settings] => Ordering K-Cup Packs
    [limit] => sample
    [goal] => 
)
```

I'll advice you create more valid variables name rather than such conversions

Comment: Just Updated it again so that your final output would still be valid

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$cleaned = new stdClass();
foreach($obj as $key => $val) {
  $newKey = str_replace(array('$','-'), '', $key);
  $cleaned->$newKey = $val;
}
print_r($cleaned);
```

Comment: I edited it, because it resulted in an infinite loop, you need to create a new object with the cleaned keys.